# Left/Right across multi-line equation

Tags: equations

I have a multi-line equation that I want to have matching sized parentheses. The advice I read online was to use `\left( equation \right. \\ left. rest-of-equation \right)` . However, this syntax leaves first half of the equation unaware of what is in the second half. For example, if you include a square root term after the break, the second parenthesis will be larger than the opening parenthesis. When you are using the `aligned` environment to split a long equation this can look somewhat offputting.

[image]

Compare the top equation to the bottom one. The parentheses match in size for the bottom equation, but the left hand parentheses for the top one is  noticeably smaller.

Top Code:

```
 \begin{aligned}[t] 
 \gamma_{\text{u}} + \frac{1}{108} 
 \left(57\gamma_{\text{er}} \right. &+  38\gamma_{\text{se}}\\ & {}\pm
 \left.\sqrt{2601 \gamma_{\text{er}}^2 + 3648
 \gamma_{\text{er}}\gamma_{\text{se}} + 1444 \gamma_{\text{se}}^2}
 \right) 
 \end{aligned}
```

Bottom Code:

```
\begin{aligned}[t] \gamma_{\text{u}} + \frac{1}{16}
\left(9\gamma_{\text{er}}  +  6\gamma_{\text{se}} \pm  \sqrt{49
\gamma_{\text{er}}^2 + 76 \gamma_{\text{er}}\gamma_{\text{se}} + 36
\gamma_{\text{se}}^2} \right) \end{aligned}
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You could also put all parts on all lines and hide the ones that don't belong with `\vphantom{...}`. That way, they'll contribute to the height, but not take up space, and your parens should match. (Me personally, I find that clutters the source too much and I'm not too fond of `\left` and `\right` anyway, so I do `\bigg` *et al.* manually in these situations.)

I also vaguely recall seeing a re-implementation that works across multiple lines, and that appears to be in `breqn`.

Comment: That is definitely a solution (`\vphantom`), but this is a table of  multiline equations with 4 other columns in the table, so the source is already cluttered as it is :D.

Comment: I'd manually size them then. I think the order is \big \Big \bigg \Bigg, but I keep forgetting.

Comment: That is the order, at least per http://garsia.math.yorku.ca/~zabrocki/latexpanel/latexpanel.pdf

Comment: A code example would help. "I do \bigg et al. manually" is vague and requires some further searching to understand the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite an old discussion but in case somebody still has a problem like that I'd recommend looking it up here http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Advanced_Mathematics#align_and_align.2A. They suggest that you should use \right. and \left. when you go to the next line. Then sizes and everything will fit and you won't have your source code completely clattered up by \vphantom stuff.

Comment: if you read the cited wikibooks entry more carefully, you will notice that if the scope of the "fenced" material exceeds a single line vertically, the `\vphantom` is still required on a line that doesn't have the same "highs" and "lows" as the line that it's supposed to match.