# Splitting an equation

Tags: formatting, equations

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{thesis}

\usepackage{amsmath}\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[left=1.25in, right=1.0in, top=1.25in, bottom=1.0in]{geometry}

\newcommand{\piRsquare}{\pi r^2}
\begin{document} \baselineskip=22pt

  \begin{equation}
    \begin{split} L(A) = c_{d} \int\limits_{0}^{\infty}  r^{d-1} \left( \frac{1}{2} \dot{A}^{2} \exp\left(-\frac{2 r^{2}}{R^{2}}\right) - \frac{1}{2}A^{2} \left(\frac{4r^{2}}{R^{4}}\right)\exp\left(-\frac{2 r^{2}}{R^{2}}\right)  \\
     &\quad - A^{2} \exp\left(-\frac{2 r^{2}}{R^{2}}\right) + A^{3} \exp\left(-\frac{3 r^{2}}{R^{2}}\right) - \frac{1}{4} A^{4} \exp\left(-\frac{4 r^{2}}{R^{2}}\right) \right) dr,
    \end{split}
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

In the above equation, where have I done wrong?

Comment: You're trying to `split` a `\left`...`\right` pair across multiple lines, which is not possible without some trickery. See [Left/Right across multiline equation](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5612/5764).

Comment: Can you solve it then I can find out the problem I have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{thesis}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[left=1.25in, right=1.0in, top=1.25in, bottom=1.0in]{geometry}

\newcommand{\piRsquare}{\pi r^2}
\begin{document} \baselineskip=22pt
    \begin{equation}
        \begin{split} L(A) = c_{d} \int\limits_{0}^{\infty} r^{d-1} \left( \frac{1}{2} \dot{A}^{2} \exp\left(-\frac{2 r^{2}}{R^{2}}\right) - \frac{1}{2}A^{2} \left(\frac{4r^{2}}{R^{4}}\right)\exp\left(-\frac{2 r^{2}}{R^{2}}\right)\right. \\
        \quad \left.- A^{2} \exp\left(-\frac{2 r^{2}}{R^{2}}\right) + A^{3} \exp\left(-\frac{3 r^{2}}{R^{2}}\right) - \frac{1}{4} A^{4} \exp\left(-\frac{4 r^{2}}{R^{2}}\right) \right) dr,
        \end{split}
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

You have imbalanced the `\right` and `\left` brackets, note the addition `\left.` and `\right.` in the code.

Answer (score 3):

As with [Left/Right across multi-line equation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5612/5764) you are attempting to split a `\left`...`\right` pair across a multi-line equation. Since you don't have variable-sized content across the lines, a simple `right.`...`\left.` pair across the break works.

Below I've highlighted the structure to show corresponding `\left`...`\right` pairs.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  L(A) &= c_{d} \int_0^\infty r^{d-1}
    \left(
      \frac{1}{2} \dot{A}^{2} \exp
      \left(
        -\frac{2 r^{2}}{R^{2}}
      \right)
      -\frac{1}{2}A^{2}
      \left(
        \frac{4r^{2}}{R^{4}}
      \right)
      \exp
      \left(
        -\frac{2 r^{2}}{R^{2}}
      \right)
    \right. \\
    & \qquad 
    \left.
      - A^{2} \exp
      \left(
        -\frac{2 r^{2}}{R^{2}}
      \right)
      + A^{3} \exp
      \left(
        -\frac{3 r^{2}}{R^{2}}
      \right)
      - \frac{1}{4} A^{4} \exp
      \left(
        -\frac{4 r^{2}}{R^{2}}
      \right)
    \right) \mathrm{d}r,
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Another option would be to avoid `\left`...`\right` pairs and use `\big`-like structures:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  L(A) &= c_{d} \int_0^\infty r^{d-1}
    \biggl(
      \frac{1}{2} \dot{A}^{2} \exp
      \biggl(
        -\frac{2 r^{2}}{R^{2}}
      \biggr)
      -\frac{1}{2}A^{2}
      \biggl(
        \frac{4r^{2}}{R^{4}}
      \biggr)
      \exp
      \biggl(
        -\frac{2 r^{2}}{R^{2}}
      \biggr)
    \\
    & \qquad 
      - A^{2} \exp
      \biggl(
        -\frac{2 r^{2}}{R^{2}}
      \biggr)
      + A^{3} \exp
      \biggl(
        -\frac{3 r^{2}}{R^{2}}
      \biggr)
      - \frac{1}{4} A^{4} \exp
      \biggl(
        -\frac{4 r^{2}}{R^{2}}
      \biggr)
    \biggr) \mathrm{d}r,
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

The advantage from such usage is that it doesn't struggle with multi-line breaking if you have have a `\big`-left on one line and a `\big`-right on another.

Answer (score 2):

There are two issues that prevent the equation from being typeset correctly:

- One mustn't let `\left[` and `\right]` span an explicit linebreak. To fix this, either provide "dummy" `\right.` and `\left.` statements on the first and last lines -- but this risks producing differently-sized "fences" in case the material enclosed by the `\left ... \right` statements differs in height across the lines -- or use explicit `\bigg` statements, as is shown in the example below.
- You have an alignment symbol, `&`, on the second line but not on the first. I suggest using something like `\qquad\quad` after the `&` symbol on the second line to ensure that the material on the second line starts to the right of the integral symbol on the first line. Alternatively, you could align the first line on `\bigg[` instead of on `=`.

I don't have the `thesis` document class on my TeX system; I've used `article` instead in the example below.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[left=1.25in, right=1.0in, top=1.25in, bottom=1.0in]{geometry}
\newcommand{\piRsquare}{\pi r^2}
\begin{document} 
%\baselineskip=22pt
\begin{equation}
\begin{split} L(A) 
&= c_{d} \int\limits_{0}^{\infty}  r^{d-1} \biggl[ 
\frac{1}{2} \dot{A}^{2} \exp\left(-\frac{2 r^{2}}{R^{2}}\right) - 
\frac{1}{2}A^{2} \left(\frac{4r^{2}}{R^{4}}\right) \exp\left(-\frac{2 r^{2}}{R^{2}}\right)  \\
&\qquad\quad % make second line start to right of
             % integral symbol on first line
- A^{2} \exp\left(-\frac{2 r^{2}}{R^{2}}\right) + 
  A^{3} \exp\left(-\frac{3 r^{2}}{R^{2}}\right) - 
\frac{1}{4} A^{4} \exp\left(-\frac{4 r^{2}}{R^{2}}\right) 
\biggr] \,dr,
\end{split}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```