# Is there a reason NOT to use \left and \right?

Tags: macros, delimiters

I was reading the [mathtools documentation](http://ctan.math.utah.edu/ctan/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/mh/mathtools.pdf) on `\DeclarePairedDelimiter`, and apparently only the starred version of the command it defines uses `\left` and `\right` on the delimiters.

This surprised me a little bit, because I've always used `\left` and `\right` on every single `\newcommand` I define which uses delimiters, I just figured there's no reason not to. Which brings me to the question.

**Is there a reason *not* to always use `\left` and `\right` on every pair of delimiter in your equations?**

Comment: Two reasons (with work-arounds): [Left/Right across multiline equation](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5612/5764); [Spacing around `\left` and `\right`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2607/5764)

Comment: A typical example is `\[\left(\sum_{i=0}^{n} i^2\right)\]`. There are other situations in which the size selected by `\left` and `\right` is too big.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At some point I was automatically generating TeX code from some language-specific syntax. I initially made all my delimiters `\left`-`\right` pairs, but stopped because they prevent line breaks. It isn't always a good idea to have line breaks in inline equations, but in my case it was a lesser evil compared with having grossly underfilled lines.

As mentioned in comments, other reasons not to use `\left` and `\right` include their sometimes overeager spacing, both horizontal and vertical. I would say that `\left` and `\right` are a good start, but then you'll want to tweak some cases manually and use `\big` and friends instead.

`\left` and `\right` need to appear on the same line in multiline equations, but that's easily solved by putting `\right.` at the end of the initial line and `\left.` at the beginning of the final line.

Comment: `\left( .. \right. \\ \left. .. \right)` will only work properly if the highest part of the equation on the first line is about the same height as that on the second line, otherwise the parenthesis won't have the same size.