# Changing ( and ) to \left( and \right)

Tags: code

Are there any plans to have the LaTeX automatically read all `(` and `)` to automatically become `\left(` and `\right)`?
If so, then when can we expect the update?

Comment: Several discussions on why this isn't as easy as you'd expect, including [this one](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31526/3345).

Comment: I hope there aren't; at least not with the current behaviour of `\left` and `\right`.

Comment: Why would you want this behavior?

Comment: There is no such plans, since you'd have even more people wanting this behaviour removed. There already exists a package or some solutions that encourage this behaviour. See [Macro for `\left(` and `\right)`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31526/5764). If this solves your problem, then this is a duplicate. Give some feedback.

Comment: @Mico Why wouldn't one want this behavior. I've been using LaTeX extensively for years and I don't see a downside.

Comment: For a posting that discusses some of the downsides of (over)using `\left` and `\right`, see [Is it ever bad to use \left and \right?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/173717/5001)

Comment: Related: [Why doesn't LaTeX interpret `(` as `\left(` and `)` as `\right)`?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/141858/5764)

Answer (score 14):

No. There are no plans to change the behaviour. As seen in many answers on this site many people over-use `\left` `\right`, when a simple `(` or a fixed size such as `\bigl(` would be preferable.

`\left\right` don't always choose the optimal size, they almost always introduce some extra horizontal space, and they have to be matched within the same TeX group which causes problems if you want to split the term over a multi-line expression.

Comment: @ColeJohnson Not sure that I understand the comment, LaTeX's current version is 2e, but in any case the behaviour of `\left\right` is really a TeX feature and not anything LaTeX can do much about.

Comment: correct. My mistake. I was thinking of TeX's version asymptotically approaching pi. Forgot about LaTex being 2e