# Underbrace without big environment-braces ( \left(\right) )

Tags: spacing, equations, cleveref, underbrace

is there a way to use `\underbrace{}_{}` inside of a `\left\right`-environment without (for example) making the braces extra-long?

And (if not): Can I set the position of the underbraced text/math lower so it doesn't collide with those braces?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper, titlepage, parskip=half]{scrbook} % Maße A4: 210x297 mm
\usepackage[a4paper,lmargin=2.5cm,rmargin=2cm,tmargin=2.5cm,bmargin=2.5cm]{geometry}    % Format und Seitenraender
% Ausgabe von Umlauten (vor 'inputenc' einbinden!)
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}        % Schoene Ausgabe von Umlauten
%------------------------------------------------------------

% Deutsche Eingabe
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}     % Umlaute direkt eingeben   UTF-8 zur besseren Zusammenarbeit mit vers. Betriebssystemen
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}     % deutsche Eingabe (Zur Eingabe von Umlauten wird 'inputenc' benötigt)
%------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{cleveref}               % Erweiterte Refernzenbefehle -- IMMER NACH hyperref lade
\crefname{enumi}{Punkt}{Punkte} % Aendert den angezeigten Namen des Labels 'enumi' in 'Punkt' bzw. 'Punkte' (Plural)
\crefname{figure}{Abbildung}{Abbildungen}
\crefname{eqation}{Gleichung}{Gleichungen}
\Crefname{equation}{Gleichung}{Gleichungen}
\crefname{subsection}{Abschnitt}{Abschnitte}
\newcommand{\udl}[1]{\underline{#1}}    %Abkuerzung fuer den Underline-Befehl

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    \rightarrow G_1 + G_2 = \sqrt{\dfrac{1}{R^2} +G_2^2} \label{eq:pi-daempfungsglied_bsp}
    \end{equation}
    \begin{align*}
        \udl{T}_B &= \dfrac{2}{ \dfrac{R}{G_2}\left( G_1 + G_2 + \dfrac{1}{R} \right)\cdot\left( G_2 + G_3 + \dfrac{1}{R} \right) -G_2\cdot R } = \dfrac{2 G_2R}{ R^2\left( \underbrace{ G_1 + G_2}_{\mathrlap{ \text{ aus \Cref{eq:pi-daempfungsglied_bsp}} }}+ \dfrac{1}{R} \right)^2 - G_2^2R^2 } \\[1.5ex]
                  &= \dfrac{ 2G_2R }{ R^2\left( \sqrt{ G_2^2 \dfrac{1}{R^2} } +\dfrac{1}{R} \right) -G_2^2 R^2 }
    \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

The result is something like this:
[image: Ugly underbrace]

Comment: Simple: don't use `\left...\right` manual scale instead

Comment: @daleif But why, when \left\right scales the braces for me?

Comment: You mean like \Big( \Big) ?

Comment: Counter question: If `\left( .. \right)` scales the braces wrongly, why use it? `\Bigl( ... \Bigr)` works much better here. See for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/135426 and the Linked questions (in the right margin).

Comment: @MichaelSchmid exactly. In many cases manually scaling is just a lot better since auto scale easily gets too large. Another example of too big: `\[ \left( \sum_i \right) \]`, using auto scaled for math in text often leads to math being too tall for the line. In general, most of the people answering here recommend using auto scale when appropriate, and manual elsewhere.

Comment: this is covered in [Underbrace in denominator with () {} (howto)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/145865) (potential duplicate)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to stick with `\left...\right` you can solve it with `\smash` that will ignore the vertical space.

```
\begin{align*}
  \udl{T}_B &= \dfrac{2}{ \dfrac{R}{G_2}\left( G_1 + G_2 + \dfrac{1}{R} \right)
    \cdot\left( G_2 + G_3 + \dfrac{1}{R} \right) -G_2\cdot R } 
  = \dfrac{2 G_2R}{ R^2\left(%
      \smash{\underbrace{ G_1 + G_2}_{\mathrlap{ \text{ aus \Cref{eq:pi-daempfungsglied_bsp}} }}}
      + \dfrac{1}{R} \right)^2 - G_2^2R^2 } \\[1.5ex]
  &= \dfrac{ 2G_2R }{ R^2\left( \sqrt{ G_2^2 \dfrac{1}{R^2} } +\dfrac{1}{R} \right) -G_2^2 R^2 }
\end{align*}
```

[image]

But I agree with the comments that often it is better to scale it yourself. Here I use`\biggl...\biggr` to get close to the same picture as above.

```
\begin{align*}
  \udl{T}_B &= \dfrac{2}{ \dfrac{R}{G_2}\biggl( G_1 + G_2 + \dfrac{1}{R} \biggr)
    \cdot\biggl( G_2 + G_3 + \dfrac{1}{R} \biggr) -G_2\cdot R } 
  = \dfrac{2 G_2R}{ R^2\biggl(%
    \underbrace{ G_1 + G_2}_{\mathrlap{ \text{ aus \Cref{eq:pi-daempfungsglied_bsp}} }}
  + \dfrac{1}{R} \biggr)^2 - G_2^2R^2} \\[1.5ex]
  &= \dfrac{ 2G_2R }{ R^2\biggl( \sqrt{ G_2^2 \dfrac{1}{R^2} } +\dfrac{1}{R} \biggr) -G_2^2 R^2 }
\end{align*}
```