# Making \left[ \right] ignore the height of \underbrace

Tags: brackets, underbrace

This question is similar to [Underbrace without big environment-braces ( \left(\right) )](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/399908/underbrace-without-big-environment-braces-left-right)
but that article isn't exactly what I need.  I need the underbrace to appear below the brackets.

The following code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb,amsthm}

\begin{document}
    \begin{equation*}
    E \left[ \smash{\underbrace{\int_0^t v^2(s) \, ds}_{\text{deterministic}}} \right] \qquad
    E \left[ \underbrace{\int_0^t v^2(s) \, ds}_{\smash{\text{deterministic}}} \right]
    \end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

produces this output:

[image]

But what I need is this:

[image]

Basically I need smash to operate on the underbrace and text, but not on the integral sign within the \underbrace argument.

Comment: Why not some predefined size like `\Biggl[ \Biggr]`?

Comment: Oh I guess that would also work :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have adopted, just for the last integral, a command macro used in this [link](https://github.com/glwagner/py2Periodic/blob/master/docs/reducedWaveEquations/reducedWaveEquations.tex), called `\mystrut`, to increase the vertical space above `underbrace`, that I have renamed:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{mathtools}
% \spvertund is a command that creates space above underbrace
\newcommand*\spvertund[1]{\vrule width0pt height0pt depth#1\relax}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[3]
\[
  E \biggl[ \underbrace{\spvertund{2.5ex}\int_0^{t} v^{2}(s) ds}_{\text{deterministic}} \biggr], \quad 
  E \Biggl[ \underbrace{\spvertund{3.5ex}\int_0^{t} v^{2}(s) ds}_{\text{deterministic}} \Biggr]
\]
\lipsum[5]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

I suggest using an explicit size rather than `\left` and `\right`.

It is possible to use `\left` and `\right`, though, by typesetting the material three times: one smashed, one with the underbrace suppressed and one for reestablishing the correct height of the material.

I also recommend other changes:

1. it's better to have a personal command for the expectation; if a reviewer pops up and orders you to typeset the “E” in a fancier font, you'll be able to do it by just changing one line of code;
2. the same holds for the differential sign; a journal you try to submit your paper to might want the “d” to be upright (unfortunately some do); with a personal command it's easier to comply; also, this `\diff` automatically adds the thin space when needed;
3. don't use `\underbrace` (or `\overbrace`) in your document: in this case it doesn't really matter (for the `\postsmash` macro to work it does, however), but in general it can lead to bad spacing;
4. when you're making the final revision, check the output for places where to add `\,` or `\!` in order to fix clashes.

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb,amsthm}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for mock text

\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\expectationargument}{[}{]}
\newcommand{\expect}{E\expectationargument}

\newcommand{\diff}{\mathop{}\!d}

\newcommand{\ubrace}[2]{{% note the additional brace
  \underbrace{#1}_{#2}%
}}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\postsmash}[1]{%
  \smash{#1}%
  \vphantom{\let\ubrace\@firstoftwo#1}%
  \gdef\fixverticalspace{\vphantom{#1}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1-4]
\begin{equation*}
\expect[\Big]{\ubrace{\int_0^t v^2(s) \diff s}{\text{deterministic}}}
\qquad
\expect[\bigg]{\,\ubrace{\int_0^t v^2(s) \diff s}{\text{deterministic}}\,}
\end{equation*}
\lipsum[2][1-4]
\begin{equation*}
\expect*{\,\postsmash{\ubrace{\int_0^t v^2(s) \diff s}{\text{deterministic}}}\,}
\fixverticalspace
\end{equation*}
\lipsum[3][1-4]
\begin{equation*}
\expect[\bigg]{\,\int_0^t v^2(s) \diff s}
\end{equation*}
where the integral is deterministic.

\end{document}
```

Final recommendation: avoid `\underbrace` as hard as possible.

[image]

Comment: These are excellent suggesions.  Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3):

Use `\biggl`-`\biggr` to adjust the brackets:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\[
  E \left[ \smash{\underbrace{\int_0^t v^2(s) \, \mathrm{d}s}_{\text{deterministic}}} \right] \qquad
  E \left[ \underbrace{\int_0^t v^2(s) \, \mathrm{d}s}_{\smash{\text{deterministic}}} \right] \qquad
  E \biggl[ \underbrace{\int_0^t v^2(s) \, \mathrm{d}s}_{\text{deterministic}} \biggr]
\]

\end{document}
```

Using `\smash` may cause the brace text to interfere with the surrounding (vertical) elements.

Answer (score 2):

Everyone's given best-practice answers (size explicitly), but, in the spirit of answering the question asked:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb,amsthm}

\begin{document}
    \begin{equation*}
    \def\filler{\int_0^t v^2(s) \, \mathrm ds}
    E \left[ \smash{\underbrace\filler_{\text{deterministic}}}\vphantom\filler \right]
    \end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

This is basically the same as @egreg's [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/529270), but maybe it's easier to see what's going on with some less macro indirection.