# Why Latex cannot compile when I add "\left[ ]\right"

Tags: equations, line-breaking

***Successful code:***

```
\documentclass[a4paper,cs4size,UTF8]{ctexart}                        
\usepackage{amsmath}                 
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
& L_1=\frac{1}{2} Trace
\left[
\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{p=1}^{i} (U_{ip}J_iU_{i1})\dot{q}_p\dot{q}_1 +\dots +     (U_{ip}J_iU_{it})\dot{q}_t \dot{q}_2+\dots +(U_{ip}J_iU_{ii})\dot{q}_p\dot{q}_i) 
\right]\\
& \quad =\frac{1}{2} Trace [\sum_{i=1}^{n} \\
&  (U_{i1}J_iU_{i1})\dot{q}_1\dot{q}_1 +\dots +(U_{i1}J_iU_{it})\dot{q}_1  \dot{q}_t+\dots +(U_{i1}J_iU_{ii})\dot{q}_1\dot{q}_i \\
& +(U_{i2}J_iU_{i1})\dot{q}_2\dot{q}_1 +\dots +(U_{ip}J_iU_{it})\dot{q}_2 \dot{q}_t+\dots +(U_{i2}J_iU_{ii})\dot{q}_2\dot{q}_i \\
& + \qquad \vdots \qquad \quad  +\qquad \qquad \vdots \qquad \qquad \quad +\qquad \qquad \vdots \\
& +(U_{ii}J_iU_{i1})\dot{q}_i\dot{q}_1 +\dots +(U_{ii}J_iU_{it})\dot{q}_t \dot{q}_2+\dots +t(U_{ii}J_iU_{ii})\dot{q}_i\dot{q}_i  ]
\end{split}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

However,when I add `\left[ ]\right`

```
\documentclass[a4paper,cs4size,UTF8]{ctexart}                        
\usepackage{amsmath}                 
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
& L_1=\frac{1}{2} Trace
\left[
\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{p=1}^{i} (U_{ip}J_iU_{i1})\dot{q}_p\dot{q}_1 +\dots +     (U_{ip}J_iU_{it})\dot{q}_t \dot{q}_2+\dots +(U_{ip}J_iU_{ii})\dot{q}_p\dot{q}_i) 
\right]\\
& \quad =\frac{1}{2} Trace \left[\sum_{i=1}^{n} \\
&  (U_{i1}J_iU_{i1})\dot{q}_1\dot{q}_1 +\dots +(U_{i1}J_iU_{it})\dot{q}_1  \dot{q}_t+\dots +(U_{i1}J_iU_{ii})\dot{q}_1\dot{q}_i \\
& +(U_{i2}J_iU_{i1})\dot{q}_2\dot{q}_1 +\dots +(U_{ip}J_iU_{it})\dot{q}_2 \dot{q}_t+\dots +(U_{i2}J_iU_{ii})\dot{q}_2\dot{q}_i \\
& + \qquad \vdots \qquad \quad  +\qquad \qquad \vdots \qquad \qquad \quad +\qquad \qquad \vdots \\
& +(U_{ii}J_iU_{i1})\dot{q}_i\dot{q}_1 +\dots +(U_{ii}J_iU_{it})\dot{q}_t \dot{q}_2+\dots +t(U_{ii}J_iU_{ii})\dot{q}_i\dot{q}_i  \right]
\end{split}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

***It failed,So my question is how to resolve this problem.***

Comment: A pair of `\left` and `\right` must appear in the same line. If one is missed, the other should be replaced by a dot. Namely, `\left[ xxx \right.` or `\left. xxx \right]`.

Comment: You cannot split a `\left`...`\right` pair across an alignment character (`&`) or line break (``\\``). You have `\left[ ... \\ ... \right]`. See [Left/Right across multiline equation](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5612/5764).

Comment: your text doesn't agree with your code.  the problem as stated in your text is that `\left[...]\right` doesn't compile.  that is because `\left` and `\right` must be followed by only a character recognized as a delimiter, or by a period.  in your description, the right delimiter character *precedes* the `\right` directive.  if this is the real question (it isn't really clear), then this is not a duplicate of the cited question.