# Use of parenthesis/curly bracket in split environment: Error for curly bracket on opposite sides of \\

Tags: align

Any help is most appreciated. Thanks!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtool}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
\begin{split}
& v \cdot \left\{ Ax + b \\
& Cx - d \right\}
\end{split}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can't have `\\ ` between `\left` and `\right` delimiters. See, for example, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5612/left-right-across-multi-line-equation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`breqn`](http://tug.org/TUGboat/tb18-3/tb56down.pdf) package for breaking equations can be used for this purpose. Albeit I think this is a trivial case to apply such a package in. The code using `brepn` is as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{breqn}
\begin{document}

\begin{dmath}
 v \cdot \left\{Ax+ b \linebreak
 Cx - d \right\}
\end{dmath}

\end{document}
```

The output in this case:

[image]

Other wise, without using `breqn` one can insert `\left .` and `\right .` to balance the curly brackets since no `\\` is allowable inside curly brackets.

The output of the first method is not satisfying, so I suggest in this case it is better to use the `aligned` environment taking into consideration balancing curly braces as mentioned above. Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
 v \cdot \left\{ \right . Ax &+ b \\
 Cx &- d \left . \right\}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

And the output is much better:

[image]