# Equation on multiple line

Tags: equations, multline

I have a mathematical expression, I try to write it in multiple line. I tried: `multline`, `equation` + `split`, `align` .. .

```
$\text{max} \left \{frac{1}{2}2x^{2}(2A+6Bx^{-4})+x(2Ax-2Bx^{-3}+\frac{1}{3}-4(Ax^{2}+Bx^{-2}+\frac{1} {3}x+1)+x+4,Ax^{2}+Bx^{-2}+\frac{1}{3}x-Ax^{2}-Bx^{-2}-\frac{1}{3}x-1   \right\}$
```

Could you please help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [`\left`/`\right` across multiline equation](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5612/5764)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option is to use the align-environment. That is really practical and allows formatting/aligning with the &-Sign

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\max \biggl\{\frac{1}{2}2x^{2}(2A+6Bx^{-4})+x(2Ax-2Bx^{-3}\frac{1]{3}-\\  
4(Ax^{2}+Bx^{-2}+\frac{1} {3}x+1)+x+4,Ax^{2}+ \\
Bx^{-2}+\frac{1}{3}x-Ax^{2}-Bx^{-2}-\frac{1}{3}x-1   \biggr\}
\end{align*}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem likely comes from the fact that `\left .. \right` cannot be used across line breaks. Use `\biggl\{` and `\biggr\}` instead. Also, instead of `\text{max}` you can use `\max`.

By the way, looks like there's a parenthesis missing on the first line, and there's a comma in the second line that looks like it doesn't belong there.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{multline}
\max \biggl\{\frac{1}{2}2x^{2}(2A+6Bx^{-4})+x(2Ax-2Bx^{-3}+\frac{1}{3}-
\\4(Ax^{2}+Bx^{-2}+\frac{1} {3}x+1)+x+4,Ax^{2}+ \\
Bx^{-2}+\frac{1}{3}x-Ax^{2}-Bx^{-2}-\frac{1}{3}x-1   \biggr\}
\end{multline}
\end{document}
```