# multi-line equation in equation environment

Tags: equations, amsmath

I'm trying to write the following equation using amsmath package in equation envoronment:

[image]

and break it into multiple lines using the following code

```
\begin{equation}
    \label{eq:eqn1}
        \begin{aligned}
            \vec{f}{}' &=\vec{\nabla}{f}                \\
                       &=\vec{\nabla}{f\left ( x, y, z \right )}                \\
                       &\approx \left ( \frac{1}{2} \left ( f\left ( x-1, y, z \right ) + f\left ( x+1, y, z \right ) \right ),  \\
                       &\qquad \frac{1}{2} \left ( f\left ( x, y-1, z \right ) + f\left ( x, y+1, z \right ) \right ),      \\
                       &\qquad \frac{1}{2} \left ( f\left ( x, y, z-1 \right ) + f\left ( x, y, z-1 \right ) \right ) \right )
        \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
```

This is giving me the following output:

[image]

I want the alignment and the line breaking the same but the final closing brace is missing here and for which I am getting error message also.

How can I get rid of this error and have the closing brace back in the equation?

Comment: `\left( ...\right)` doesn't work over ampersants. replace it with  `& \bigg(` and `\bigg)` or `left( <first line > \right.` and `& \left. <last line>\right)`.

Comment: @Zarko Thanks. I choose the second option you have mentioned and it's working now.

Comment: potential duplicate: [`\left`/`\right` across multiline equation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5612)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `&` with `\left ... right` if you load `mathtools` (needless to load `amsmath` in this case) and use its `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` and `\MTkillspecial` commands. I adapted an example in the documentation to define a `\parens` command, which can break across lines. Its starred version adds a pair of implicit `\left \right` around the parentheses. Alternatively to fine-tune the size of the parentheses, you can use an optional argument: `[\big]`, `[\Big]`, &c.

I took the opportunity to improve your layout and simplify your code, removing all unnecessary pairs of `left \right`, using a nested `aligned` environment, the medium-sized fractions from `nccmath` from the 1/2 coefficients,  and the nicer-looking arrows from `esvect`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools, nccmath}
\usepackage[b]{esvect} 

    \newcommand\MTkillspecial[1]{% helper macro
    \bgroup
    \catcode`\&=9
    \let\\\relax%
    \scantokens{#1}%
    \egroup
    }
    \DeclarePairedDelimiter\parens()
    \reDeclarePairedDelimiterInnerWrapper\parens{star}{
    \mathopen{#1\vphantom{\MTkillspecial{#2}}\kern-\nulldelimiterspace\right.}
    #2
    \mathclose{\left.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace\vphantom{\MTkillspecial{#2}}#3}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    \label{eq:eqn1}
        \begin{aligned}
            \vv{f}{}' &=\vv{\nabla}{f} \\
                       &= \vv{\nabla}{f( x, y, z)} \\
                       &\approx \begin{aligned}[t] \parens*{ & \mfrac{1}{2} \bigl( f( x-1, y, z) + f( x+1, y, z) \bigr), \\
                        & \mfrac{1}{2} \bigl( f( x, y-1, z) + f( x, y+1, z) \bigr), \\
                       & \mfrac{1}{2} \bigl( f( x, y, z-1) + f( x, y, z-1) \bigr)
                       }\end{aligned}
        \end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Shouldn't the OP be placing the final three rows in a `pmatrix` environment?

Comment: I don't think so: clearly, it's a set of three coordinates, which should make up a row matrix if the page were wide enough – not a column matrix.

Comment: @Bernard Great. Will it provide me the flexibility to choose between manual line break and automated line break depending on the page width. For example, in the given equation, the first two terms on the RHS can be written on a single line while the third one will go to the next line. Can it also be done using your framework without bothering for line breaks? Basically, in some cases, I need the kind of formatting I asked here, but there are cases where I prefer that my code will take care of the line break along with the alignment depending on the equation length and page width.

Comment: @Majis: The only package which caters for automatic line breaking I know is `breqn`, but I never used it. In general, I prefer to have full control on line breaking in equations.

Answer (score 1):

The following may be close to what you're looking for (`^T` denotes the transpose operator):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\label{eq:eqn1}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.25}
  \begin{aligned}[b]
    \vec{f}' =\vec{\nabla} f   
      &=\vec{\nabla} f(x, y, z)    \\
      &\approx 
        \begin{pmatrix} 
          \frac{1}{2} [ f(x-1, y, z) + f(x+1, y, z) ]  \\
          \frac{1}{2} [ f(x, y-1, z) + f(x, y+1, z) ]  \\
          \frac{1}{2} [ f(x, y, z-1) + f(x, y, z-1) ] 
        \end{pmatrix} ^{\!\!T}
  \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is really a nice way to represent the equation.