# Exponent in Two lines in latex

Tags: equations, superscripts, multline

I want to write the exponent, but my equation exponent is too long and cannot write in one line it cut from page.

```
 \begin{multline*}
    \phi_{m}(\mathcal{K}_{1}\mathcal{K}_{2},C_{2})=\phi((\\g^{\theta
    d_{1}^{*} (\alpha + r_{1}^{i}
    (ID_{i}+(ID_{1}+ID_{2}+\dots+ID_{i-1}+ID_{i+1}+\dots
    ID_{m}))+((r_{1}^{1}ID_{1}+r_{1}^{2}ID_{2}+\dots+r_{1}^{i-1}ID_{i-1}+ID_{i}+r_{1}^{i+1}ID_{i+1}+\dots+r_{1}^{m}ID_{m})))}\\g^{\theta d_{2}^{*}(-r_{1}^{i}-{(r_{1}^{1}+r_{1}^{2}+\dots+r_{1}^{i-1}+r_{1}^{i+1}+\dots+r_{1}^{m})})}\\g^{\sigma
    d_{3}^{*}(r_{2}^{i}(
    ID_{i}+(r_{2}^{1}ID_{1}+r_{2}^{2}ID_{2}+\dots+r_{2}^{i-1}ID_{i-1}+ID_{i}+r_{2}^{i+1}ID_{i+1}+\dots+r_{2}^{m}ID_{m})+(ID_{1}+ID_{2}+\dots+ID_{i-1}+ID_{i+1}+\dots+ID_{m}))}\\g^{\sigma
    d_{4}^{*}(-r_{2}^{i}-(r_{2}^{1}+r_{2}^{2}+\dots+r_{2}^{i-1}+r_{2}^{i+1}+\dots+r_{2}^{m}))} ,(g^{s_{1}d_{1}+s_{1}(ID_{1},ID_{2},\dots,ID_{m})d_{2}+s_{2}d_{3}+s_{2}(ID_{1},ID_{2},\dots,ID_{m})d_{4}})
    ) \end{multline*}
```

Here the first power of g cannot completed in one line.
Please help me in doing this.

Comment: 12th question: MWE. You may be able to introduce a symbol that represents the exponent. The symbol is explained on a different line.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5612

Comment: That's a ridiculously long power.  How would you write that by hand without anyone getting confused partway through?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=2.5cm]{geometry} % set page layout options
\newcommand\ID{\mathit{I}\mkern-4mu\mathit{D}}
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
&\phi_m(\mathcal{K}_1\mathcal{K}_2,C_2) =\phi\{ \\ 
&\quad g^{\theta d_1^* [\alpha + r_1^i
    (\ID^{}_i+(\ID^{}_1+\ID^{}_2+\dots+\ID^{}_{i-1}+\ID^{}_{i+1}+\dots\ID^{}_m))
    +(r_1^1\ID^{}_1+r_1^2\ID^{}_2+\dots+r_1^{i-1}\ID^{}_{i-1}
    +\ID^{}_i+r_1^{i+1}\ID^{}_{i+1}+\dots+r_1^m\ID^{}_m)]}\\
&\quad g^{\theta d_2^*[-r_1^i-{(r_1^1+r_1^2+\dots
    +r_1^{i-1}+r_1^{i+1}+\dots+r_1^m)}]}\\
&\quad g^{\sigma d_3^*[r_2^i(\ID^{}_i+(r_2^1\ID^{}_1
    +r_2^2\ID^{}_2+\dots+r_2^{i-1}\ID^{}_{i-1}+\ID^{}_i
    +r_2^{i+1}\ID^{}_{i+1}+\dots+r_2^m\ID^{}_m)+(\ID^{}_1+\ID^{}_2
    +\dots+\ID^{}_{i-1}+\ID^{}_{i+1}+\dots+\ID^{}_m)]}\\
&\quad g^{\sigma d_4^*[-r_2^i-(r_2^1+r_2^2+\dots
    +r_2^{i-1}+r_2^{i+1}+\dots+r_2^m)]} ,\\
&\quad (g^{s_1d_1+s_1(\ID_1,\ID_2,\dots,\ID_m)d_2
    +s_2d_3
    +s_2(\ID_1,\ID_2,\dots,\ID_m)d_4}
      )
\} 
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```