# getting error in greater than and less than in equation

Tags: equations, amsmath

getting error in this equation

```
\begin{equation*}
r =
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
& a_p  \text{if }  \sum\limits_{p=1}^L a_p   &>&  \sum\limits_{q=1}^s a_q   \\
& a_q  \text{if }  \sum\limits_{p=1}^L a_p   &<&  \sum\limits_{q=1}^s a_q  
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
```

Comment: You are missing a closing `\right.` to match the opening `\left\{`. Also, you should consider using `cases` environment. Oh, just noticed that you probably want to use `\text{ if }` (space _before_ `if`) instead of `\text{if }`.

Comment: Your issue is related to [Left/Right across multi-line equation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5612/5764) (and therefore a duplicate of that question). However, your problem is solved by something altogether.

Comment: I wanted to use a mltiline equation with left bracealone

Comment: space before if provided. still giving error

Answer (score 1):

You can't let `\left` and `\right` span an alignment `&` naturally. You need to break them using a `\left`-`\right.` and `\left.`-`\right` pair, together with the optional `\vphantom`s to have similar vertical heights (as described in [Left/Right across multi-line equation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5612/5764)).

However, your problem is solved using either `cases` or `dcases`, depending on which you prefer:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\[
  r = \begin{cases}
    a_p & \text{if } \sum_{p = 1}^L a_p > \sum_{q = 1}^s a_q \\
    a_q & \text{if } \sum_{p = 1}^L a_p < \sum_{q = 1}^s a_q
  \end{cases}
\]

\[
  r = \begin{dcases}
    a_p & \text{if } \sum_{p = 1}^L a_p > \sum_{q = 1}^s a_q \\
    a_q & \text{if } \sum_{p = 1}^L a_p < \sum_{q = 1}^s a_q
  \end{dcases}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: I am using   \usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
packages.So if i use  \usepackage{mathtools}
again,it gives error saying that it already exists. How will I rectify this?

Comment: @poorna: I get no such error message. Since [`mathtools`](//ctan.org/pkg/mathtools) loads [`amsmath`](//ctan.org/pkg/amsmath), what about `\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}`?

Comment: how to allign eqn number here?????

Comment: @poorna: Can you provide some minimal code that one could examine in order to see what you're having problems with?

Comment: \begin{equation*}
r =
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
& a_p  \text{if }  \sum\limits_{p=1}^L a_p   &>&  \sum\limits_{q=1}^s a_q   \\
& a_q  \text{if }  \sum\limits_{p=1}^L a_p   &<&  \sum\limits_{q=1}^s a_q  
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

Comment: the same code above but equation number is not aligned

Comment: @poorna: You're using `equation*` which doesn't print equation numbers. Here's a minimal example that replicates your output and doesn't use `aligned` but `dcases` (a `\displaystyle` equivalent of `cases`): [code](https://pastebin.com/raw/xAb5Gth9) Where do you want the equation numbers? With each of the choices within the `cases`? For that you'll need to use the `numcases` environment from the [`cases` package](//ctan.org/pkg/cases).